# Memory Leak (false positive) when an MFC applications uses a DLL

Tags: c++, dll, memory-leaks, mfc

I develop a C++ Library (DLL). When I create a minimal MFC project (VS2017) that links with this DLL its okay. But as soon as any function of the library is used by the MFC application the debugger of the MFC project complains about memory leaks (many lines like the ones below):

```
Detected memory leaks!
Dumping objects ->
{2255} normal block at 0x000002A4B1F8C360, 48 bytes long.
 Data: <                > 10 BB F8 B1 A4 02 00 00 B0 BD F8 B1 A4 02 00 00 
{2242} normal block at 0x000002A4B1F8BDB0, 48 bytes long.
 Data: <                > C0 C0 F8 B1 A4 02 00 00 F0 C2 F8 B1 A4 02 00 00 
{2220} normal block at 0x000002A4B1F8C2F0, 48 bytes long.
 Data: <                > 80 C2 F8 B1 A4 02 00 00 10 C9 F8 B1 A4 02 00 00
```

These are false positives because it occurs also when only an empty test function of the library is called. Moreover this does not happen when the library is linked with a non-MFC project.

What can cause these warnings? Related information:

- A VS2013 user said that he can avoid the warnings by changing the
  character set of his MFC project. I have tested that in VS2017 but
  get still warnings.
- A VS2017 user said that the warnings are gone when he delay-loads
  the DLL.
- In the course of debugging I have compiled the DLL with CMake in order to use settings which are as standard as possible. But no change.

Comment: Check your build settings. Are both the .exe and the .dll using MFC as a DLL? Same version (Debug etc.)?

Comment: Same version, Debug, x64. The dll does not use MFC. Does it need to?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't catch that. I'm thinking that the root cause is that the .exe and the .dll are using two different versions of the runtime library, and you're seeing objects that are allocated by one but released in the other.

Comment: I'm a Linux developer and do not use MFC in my projects, thus the question: Does that mean that the DLL must use MFC when it shall be linked with an MFC executable? But it happens also when I call just an empty function of the DLL where no memory is allocated or released.

Comment: Better post the code of that empty test function (the prototype, arguments etc) and the way you link it to the application (static, dynamic etc).

Comment: Is one compiled with Unicode and the other with MBCS? I've experienced it when settings are mixed.

Comment: The Visual Studio project of the DLL has used default settings (the character set field was empty). The MFC project of the application used Unicode. Changing the character set to Multibyte solved the problem in VS2013 but didn't change anything in VS2017.

Comment: @ConstantineGeorgiou, the signature of the test method was static void Fade_2D::dummyFunc().  The library has been linked by adding its *.lib file to Linker->Input->Additional Dependencies.